# Проблемы с установкой ОС через PXE

Tags: windows, ssd, uefi, pxe

Всем добрый день, случилась беда, при этом предпосылки и причины установить не представляется возможным, но обо всём по порядку.

Есть ноутбук Thinkpad T470s, который сперва нужно было переформатировать. И проблемы были уже на этом этапе, так как CMD (форматирование делал через Diskpart) ссылалась на неверный синтаксис после того как висела до получаса на 0 процентов. Но я не отчаялся и переформатировал SSD с помощью GParted'a (инструмент Live CD Linux (конкретно -- Mint)). Кстати, причина форматирование -- наличие битлокера.

После того как разобрался с форматированием, я принялся устанавливать Windows 10 через PXE, но и тут начались сложности: диалог установки с помощью PXE и USB-носителя заканчивался ошибкой, отсылающей к проблеме с носителем (0x800700A1 и 0x80070057 соответственно). При этом состояние SSD-диска нормальное.

Так как изучить носитель досконально не представляется возможным. Потому я купил новый, но проблемы не закончились: на этот раз установка ОС с помощью флешки оканчивалась успехом, а через PXE -- ошибкой 102. При этом процесс установки Windows на другие ноутбуки с помощью PXE проходит в штатном режиме.

Стоит отметить, что к настройкам UEFI у компании есть требования, а именно: запуск только UEFI, поддержка CSM отключена и Secure Boot включен (ковырять настройки UEFI я пробовал, но толку нет). Кстати, при запуске PXE ноутбук пытается наладить связь с сервером через IPv4 только со второго раза, хотя первым в очереди IPv4 и стоит. А

Поэтому суть моего вопроса проста: в чём может быть проблема, либо как можно её выявить, а также как решить проблему с установкой через PXE?

Comment: Эммм... а какая реализация pxe?

Answer (score 0):

Если проблема повторяется только на одном устройстве, и очень хочется чтобы установка ос была произведена только через PXE, то можно пойти следующим путем, например подключить ssd от ноутбука на другой ПК с установленной ролью Hyper-V или c VirtualBox(через RAW VMDK диск), в диспетчере дисков переключить ssd в режим offline, создать чистую ВМ и подключить физический диск в нее, и выбрать режим установки ОС по сети. запустить ВМ. проверить как пройдет установка.
Возможно есть какие-то баги у биоса, и стоит попробовать выключить Secure Boot, но оставить включенным UEFI, на работе часто сталкивался с глючками при установке через PXE на старых материнских платах поддержка UEFI+Secure Boot хоть и была заявлена, но фактически не работала.

Comment: Хоть и костыль, но звучит работоспособно. К сожалению, после подключения к серверу, нужно логиниться в PXE аккаунт и одним из требований к установке являются указанные требования к UEFI. Вообще, я ещё раз подумал и самый очевидный но от того не менее рабочий вариант -- это поставить систему на другом ноут

Comment: Ну у меня работал такой вариант. когда система по PXE не грузилась. на 10ке UEFI по PXE должен работать. на чем вообще сервер загрузки? SCCM или просто Windows Server?

Comment: Сам по себе Secure Boot можно включить уже после установки. Эта настройка по сути ничего особо не повышает в части безопасности. Я думаю, майки ее придумали чтобы усложнить установку своих же старых осей на новые ПК. Ну и рикошетом оно ударило по линуксам. Но с тех пор как был подписан граб и он стал поддерживать безопасную загрузку из него уже можно что угодно стартовать, и потом уже передать управление ОС поэтому наврядли оно сильно помешает вирусам и руткитам которые захотят обойти безопасную загрузку.

Comment: Да, используется SCCM, поэтому отрубить на время установки Secure Boot не получится, так как происходит проверка настроек UEFI. Вообще, странное положение дел

Comment: а ты не пробовал изучать логи SCCM в части PXE клиента они при сбое на диске создаются. до ребута их можно скопировать и посмотреть в чем ошибка не всегда помогает. но хоть что-то.

Comment: если в ссцм драйвера для задач накиданы все до кучи и от разных материнок, то бывают забавные глюики типа винда поставилась все работает все ок. потом тыкаешь на эксель даблкликом по ярлыку и синий экран. нажимаешь пуск открываешь эксель внутри делаешь файл открыть все работает. тыкаешь по файлу еще раз. опять синий экран.

Comment: Чёрт возьми, это здравая очевидная идея!